# Truncate sentence to a certain number of words

Tags: javascript

How can a sentence be truncated to a certain number of words (NB. not letters)?

I thought to use `split(" ")`, but then how do I count out words?

For example:

- `Javascript word count cut off` => `Javascript word count`
- `Want better search results? See our search tips!` => `Want better search`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: @Oded, many of answer use `string length` to cut letters. so that the words will be broken.

Comment: @fish: That is not what Oded asked!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, em, firstly i missed in the `string length` and not remember the `join`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`split` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
"Want better search results? See our search tips".split(" ").splice(0,3).join(" ")
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, ok, forgive me as a starter for learning web tech.

Comment: Is there something faster than `split`, `splice` and `join`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a "read more" function I wrote for my Meteor app. It accepts a maxWords parameter and strips html tags using jquery's text() method.

Hope it helps!

```
function readMore(string, maxWords) {       
    var strippedString = $("<p>" + string + "</p>").text().trim();      
    var array = strippedString.split(" ");
    var wordCount = array.length;
    var string = array.splice(0, maxWords).join(" ");

    if(wordCount > maxWords) {
        string += "...";
    }

        return string ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pure solution with ES6, defaults to 10 words

```js
const truncate = (str, max = 10) => {
  const array = str.trim().split(' ');
  const ellipsis = array.length > max ? '...' : '';

  return array.slice(0, max).join(' ') + ellipsis;
};
```

Comment: Why do you use const and not var?

Answer (score -2):

Splitting works, as you have described it. If you use a RegExp, however, you don't have to split the whole string:

```
var str = "Lions and tigers and bears";
var exp = /[A-Z|a-z]+/g;

var a = exp.exec(str); // Lions
var b = exp.exec(str); // and
var c = exp.exec(str); // tigers
```

Comment: `[A-Z|a-z]` will match `A-Z`, `|` and `a-z`. Inside a character class, `|` as no special meaning. If you want to use case-insensitivity, just use the `i` modifier. Better might be to use `\w` anyway: `/\w+/g`.

Comment: @Timbits, that is also a great method, but if the `str` is chinese or latin words, or even a json data, it is not easy use `/[A-Z|a-z]+/g`.